# Nuxt 3 SSR resets some img height and widht to 0

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, cloudflare-pages

I am currently attempting to deploy a basic Nuxt 3 blog page on CloudFlare Pages. To generate the files, I used `npm run generate` as the build command. However, most of the images reset their width and height to 0 after loading. Upon viewing the source code, I noticed that the code contains `width="auto"` and `height="auto"` as intended, but it gets reset in the DOM later on. This issue occurs on most, but not all, of the images, so I'm confused as it happens only in production.

Here is a sample code:

```
                    <img
                        src="/pics/dashboard_click_to_start.png"
                        title="Click here to start button"
                        alt="Screenshot of Click here to start button"
                        class="mx-auto u-photo"
                        loading="lazy"
                        width="auto"
                        height="auto" />
                </div>
```